# Can we write the complex Hopf line bundle as a pull-back?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, projective-space

Consider complex projective space $\Bbb CP^n$. Then define $$L = \{ (\ell, z) \in \Bbb CP^n\times \Bbb C^{n+1} \mid z \in \ell  \}.$$Then $L$ is a complex line bundle over $\Bbb CP^n$. The projection is the obvious one and it is clear that each fibre is a vector space of dimension $1$. Then we're left to check the local trivialization postulate.

I'm not so used to work with projective spaces, so I was trying to write $L$ as a pull-back of any another bundle, to no avail. Maybe defining trivializations is not so hard after all, but I guess that trying to write $L$ as a pull-back is an interesting question on its own... so, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can write any complex line bundle over a paracompact space as the pullback of the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, but I guess this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the comment. Rigorously, this answers the question, but I think this is a bit far for me at the moment :P

Comment: Calculating transition functions here is not difficult.

Comment: Take $v_\ell \in \ell$ with $\|v_\ell\| = 1$, where $\|\cdot\|$ comes from the usual hermitean inner product in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$. I want to write $\varphi(\ell,z) = (\ell, \langle z, v_\ell\rangle)$, and with this formula the transition seems to be the identity. But I'm missing some detail about the domain of that trivialization candidate. Otherwise that bundle would be trivial...

Comment: This is the grandmother bundle for everything, @Ivo, so I don't think you'll find it in any more basic way than it already arises. Indeed, the tautological rank $k$-bundle on $G(k,n)$ is equally universal. If you have a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$, its Gauss map (mapping point to tangent plane) pulls the tautological bundle back to the tangent bundle of the submanifold. And in the $\Bbb CP^n$ case, you're pulling $L$ back to the normal bundle by the usual Gauss map of a hypersurface in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$. (Everything works in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, too.)